# How to filter records based on key click?

Tags: javascript, html, events, html-table

I am C++ programmer and new to JS. I am trying to filter table based on click event. I have following table. How can i keep records based on clicking keys and filtering other records.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border =1 cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="width:100%">
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Marks</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="22"> 22<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="23"> 23 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="24"> 24<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="25"> 25 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="29"> 29<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="45"> 45 <br>

</body>
</html>
```

In the above example if i click on 23 only record with id 23 should be displayed and rest should be filtered out.

Comment: Are you willing to accept a jQuery-based solution?

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a jQuery-based solution, I have whipped up one. The logic of the code is pretty simple: we trigger the filtering function whenever a `change` event is detected on any of the checkboxes, with a caveat:

- if no checkboxes are checked, we show all table rows, but
- if one or more are checked, we proceed with the filtering

For the filtering function:

1. We first hide all table rows.
2. Then, we map all the values of checked checkboxes into an array, say `vals`. This is done by using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), which returns the value of each element. We chain [`.get()` after `.map()` in order to retrieve the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795318/map-get-confusion).
3. Use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to compare the text node in each of the table row's first table cell, to see if the text node matches any one of the elements in the array. If it does, we return them and show them.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    // We check if one or more checkboxes are selected
    // If one or more is selected, we perform filtering
    if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
      // Get values all checked boxes
      var vals = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
      }).get();

      // Here we do two things to table rows
      // 1. We hide all
      // 2. Then we filter, show those whose value in first <td> matches checkbox value
      $('table tr')
      .hide()    // 1
      .filter(function() {    // 2
        return vals.indexOf($(this).find('td:first').text()) > -1;
      }).show();
    } else {
      // Show all
      $('table tr').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border =1 cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="width:100%">
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Marks</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="22"> 22<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="23"> 23 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="24"> 24<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="25"> 25 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="29"> 29<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="45"> 45 <br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it using Javascript, here a raw working example using jQuery library: http://jsfiddle.net/zn8ocm43/1/

The idea is that when you click on the row you trigger a Javascript function which hide all other rows, when you click again on the selected row the other rows are shown again.

To hide a row you can add a css class to it with

```
display:none
```

Furthermore, it would be better to separate  header row from data rows using thead and tbody tags: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp

If you are willing to use jQuery you can find plugins which do all the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i got it right, but i think he's wanting to filter by columns.
If that's what he's searching for, here's a quick script in pure js:

```js
function NodeListToArray (nodeList) {
 var arr = [];

 for (var i = nodeList.length >>> 0; i--;)
  arr[i] = nodeList[i];

 return arr;
}

function filter (rows, columnIndex) {
 rows.forEach(function (row, i) {
  for (var k = 0; k < rows[i].children.length; k++) {
   if (k === columnIndex || !~columnIndex) 
    rows[i].children[k].style.visibility = 'initial';
   else
    rows[i].children[k].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
 });
}

var rows = NodeListToArray(document.querySelectorAll('tr'));

for (var i = 0; i < rows[0].children.length; i++) {
 rows[0].children[i].addEventListener('click', function (index, e) {
  filter(rows, index);
 }.bind(null, i));
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
 filter(rows, -1);
});
```

```html
<table border =1 cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="width:100%">
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Marks</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button>Show All</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by another way too using jquery

```js
$(function(){
   $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    $("table tr td:first-child").each(function(){
     $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("hideCls");
    });
    var chBoxVal=$(this).attr("value");
    $("table tr td:first-child").each(function(){
     if($(this).text()==chBoxVal)
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass("showCls");
     else
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass("hideCls");
    });
   });
  });
```

```css
.hideCls{
   display:none;
  }
.showCls{
   display:table-row;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border =1 cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="width:100%">
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Marks</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>25</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="22"> 22<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="23"> 23 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="24"> 24<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="25"> 25 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="29"> 29<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="45"> 45 <br>
```

Comment: But if you check multiple checkboxes everything gets hidden.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same by passing array (of ids) on clicking a div element?