# How to filter records by clicking div array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This refers to my previous question.

[how to filter records based on key click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28063963/how-to-filter-records-based-on-key-click)

But now i am trying to communicate between div element array and table so how can i filter records based on div array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function() { // on page load
                $('#myElId').data('nameYourData', ["22","23","24"]); 
                var myData = $('#myElId').data('nameYourData');
                $("#showMyData").text(myData);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myElId">Some element</div><br/>
        MyData:<div id="showMyData"></div>

        <a href="filter_records()">MyData:<div id="showMyData"></div></a> 

        <script> 
            $(function() {
                $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
                    // We check if one or more checkboxes are selected
                    // If one or more is selected, we perform filtering
                    if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
                        // Get values all checked boxes
                        var vals = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function() {
                            return this.value;
                        }).get();

                        // Here we do two things to table rows
                        // 1. We hide all
                        // 2. Then we filter, show those whose value in first <td> matches checkbox value
                        $('table tr')
                            .hide()    // 1
                            .filter(function() {    // 2
                                return vals.indexOf($(this).find('td:first').text()) > -1;
                            }).show();
                    } else {
                        // Show all
                        $('table tr').show();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <table border =1 cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Marks</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>Smith</td>      
                <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>Jackson</td>        
                <td>94</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>Doe</td>        
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>Doe</td>        
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>Doe</td>        
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>Doe</td>        
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="22"> 22<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="23"> 23 <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="24"> 24<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="25"> 25 <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="29"> 29<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="45"> 45 <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

But how can i implement it by clicking on text (like href) and showdata variable should be passed in function and rows should be filtered.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a couple divs that correspond to different portion of data in your table? By clicking on respective divs, hide other data in table that is not associated with this div?

Comment: Yes, I have many divs

Comment: Just a comment, you don't need to load jQuery twice. Once is more than enough.

Comment: Can u pls post example as i am not good in JS/JQuery but i am C Programmer.

Comment: @DavidBarker once is more than enough? So he needn't load jQuery at all?

Comment: dear experts can u pls post any working example as i am new to JS world.

Comment: [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) could prove useful for this

Comment: @DavidBarker stating that "one is more than enough" means literally, that he does not need it at all. Just say "one is enough".

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code a bit. May be this example could be helpful to you?
Paste into a html file and see it work.

Edit: modified code due to change in request
Edit2: modified again to put the filter in functions

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){   

                var filterList = [22,23,24];

                //-----Code to implement click listener---
                $('#showMyDataButton').click(function(){
                    if($(this).hasClass('clickableDivOff')){
                        //--------------------------
                        // Turn on Filter
                        //--------------------------

                        //change button effects
                        $(this).removeClass('clickableDivOff');
                        $(this).addClass('clickableDivOn');
                        $(this).text('Filter is on');

                        //applying filter
                        TurnOnFilter(filterList);
                    } else {
                        //--------------------------
                        // Turn off Filter
                        //--------------------------

                        //change button effects
                        $(this).removeClass('clickableDivOn');
                        $(this).addClass('clickableDivOff');
                        $(this).text('Filter is off');

                        //applying filter
                        TurnOffFilter();
                    }
                });
            });

            function TurnOnFilter(filterList){
                //hide all rows first (but not table header);
                $('#dataTable tr').hide();
                $('#dataTable tr:nth-child(1)').show();

                //iterate each id in the filter list
                //within each iteration, check all rows to find a matching id
                // displays matching row.
                for(var i=0;i<filterList.length;i++){
                    $('#dataTable td:nth-child(1)').each(function(){
                        if($(this).text().trim()==filterList[i]){
                            $(this).parent().show();
                        } 
                    });
                }
            }

            function TurnOffFilter(){
                //simple show all the rows
                $('#dataTable tr').show();
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            .clickableDiv{
                border: 2px solid #ddd;
                width: 200px;
                text-align:center;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .clickableDivOn{
                font-weight:bold;
                color: white;
                background-color: #58BE97;
            }

            .clickableDivOff{
                font-weight:bold;
                color: white;
                background-color: #EF9012;
            }

            table td, table th{
                width:33%;
                padding-left:5px;
                text-align:left;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Filter Test</h2>

        <div id="showMyDataButton" class="clickableDiv clickableDivOff">Filter is off</div>

        <p></p>

        <table id="dataTable" border =1 cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Marks</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>Smith</td>      
                <td>50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>Jackson</td>        
                <td>94</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>Doe</td>        
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>Doe</td>        
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>Doe</td>        
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>Doe</td>        
                <td>80</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks but show my button filter everything, it should filter based on array ids in here (22, 23, 24).

Comment: if you check the checkboxes 22,23,24 before turning on the filter, then they only those 3 records will appear

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply! I don't want to use check box i just pasted checkboxes to show my previous working example. I need to filter based on array only.

Comment: I have modified the code to use an array of filter id

Comment: Thanks for kind help! how can i pass array as parameter? As far as i know document.ready function does not accept any value.

Comment: I think still array is hard coded not as parameter.

Comment: TurnOnFilter takes an array. Therefore you should figure out how are you going to get this array of filter. and pass it into TurnOnFilter(filterList.)

Comment: Can i pass array outside?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69398/discussion-between-ji-in-coding-and-user15662).

Comment: I checked when i used the same in table first one works while second one does not. <table>    <tr>
         <script>
           var filterList = [22,23,24,45];
          TurnOnFilter(filterList);
         </script>
         <td><div id="showMyDataButton" class="clickableDiv clickableDivOff">3</div></td>
         <td>$100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <script>
           var filterList = [22,23];
            TurnOnFilter(filterList);
        </script>
         <td><div id="showMyDataButton" class="clickableDiv clickableDivOff">5</div></td>
         <td>$80</td>
     </tr>
     </table>

Comment: That is precisely the reason why i mentioned earlier those js code should be placed in $(document).ready(); When the browser parses your script tag, it attempts to execute TurnOnFilter(filterList) even before the rest of your table html code has been rendered. Thus it cannot find those elements it is looking for. If you place the script tag after the table element, it will work.

Comment: I have tried putting script later but still same pblm. I have uploaded my code here http://www.filedropper.com/data_26.

Comment: I have editted your file. http://www.filedropper.com/data_28  This is the furthest I'd help you on this one.

Comment: Thanks but in my case i may have 1000's of rows so i cannot define many function one for each row. How can i fix this issue.

Comment: you should post another thread, and describe your problem in that new thread. because what you are asking now is really out of the context of this thread.