# How to filter rows based on value?

Tags: jquery, html, filter, html-table

This refers to my previous question.

[How to filter records by clicking div array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28089781/how-to-filter-records-by-clicking-div-array/28090803#comment44670945_28090803)

I have one table which has ids as last column and on clicking ids I need to filter rows of second table (just to keep the records which matches with ids of table1) and filter others.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border=1 style="width:100%">
<th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Ids</th>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Book</td>       
    <td>50,23,34</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Cook</td>       
    <td>94,23,45,23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Teacher</td>        
    <td>80,12,34,45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ram</td>
    <td>Miner</td>      
    <td>50,56,67,45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Raj</td>
    <td>Engineer</td>       
    <td>94,23,12,34,56,23</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gav</td>
    <td>Principal</td>      
    <td>80,67,89,45,23,12</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<br><br>

<B>Index Table</B>
<br>

<table id="dataTable" border =1 cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="width:100%">
<tr><th>Ids</th><th>Class</th><th>Marks</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>Class1</td> 
    <td>250</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>Class2</td> 
    <td>294</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>Class3</td> 
    <td>250</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>Class1</td> 
    <td>294</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>Class1</td> 
    <td>250</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>Class3</td> 
    <td>294</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>Class1</td> 
    <td>250</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>67</td>
    <td>Class2</td> 
    <td>294</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>89</td>
    <td>Class2</td> 
    <td>250</td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>Class1</td> 
    <td>250</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Class1</td> 
    <td>294</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>56</td>
    <td>Class1</td> 
    <td>250</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

In the previous question, every time I need to assign function id to each row and define function for each row, but my tables may have millions of rows so not possible to do it manually. How can this be automated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understood, when the user clicks a  in the column IDs of the first table it filters the second table , showing only the ids stored in the clicked div.

Put the id on the first table :

```
<table id="first-table" border="1" style="width:100%">
```

And edit in the first table the TD's containing the ids :

```
<td id="td-containing-ids">id1,id2,id3</td>
```

(i suggest here to use css instead of obsolete html syntax & inline styling)

this should work:

```
// checks if 'value' is in 'array' 
function isInArray(value, array) {
  return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}

// will select rows based on the text attribute og this
// in 'this' will be stored the <td> you just clicked
function selectRows() {

    // get the ids in a string
    var ids = $(this).text().split(',');
    var display; // a little trick to avoid more code

    // iterate through every row of the second table
    // this is not a very optimal way to do it, but you get it ;)
    $('#dataTable tr td:first-child').each(function(){

        // in 'this' is stored the first <td> of the second table(of each row, of course)
        if( isInArray( $(this).text(), ids ) ) {
            // this means the id is found in the 'ids' array
            display = 'block'; //or whatever suits you here
        }
        else {
            // this means the id of the row is not in the 'ids' array
            display = 'none'
        }
        $(this).parent().css('display', display);
    });

}
// use event delegation when you have a bunch of elements
$('#first-table').on('click', '#td-containing-ids', selectRows);
```

this is not very performant if you have very much ids stored and much rows in the second table. i hope you understand it :).

So what am i doing here:
-attach event handler to every  in the first table
(i did this with event delegating, which is a good practice if you have much elements and want to attach events on everyone, [see this](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for more information.)

- get the text from the clicked
- the text that we just got is in fact our ids which we want to show on the second table
- we put them in an array
- we traverse the second table, row by row
- we get the text from  with the id(from the second row)
- if this id is inside our first array , the row is made visible
  (through display: block/table-row)
- if this id is not inside our first array, the row is made INvisible
  (through display: none)

**errors in my code:**
-we traverse with every click the first table, each row of it, so at every user-interaction, jQuery has to traverse DOM...which IF you have much rows in the second table, this is NOT good. If you don't add after page load other rows in the second table, you can fetch the rows from the second table at runtime and store them in an array( only the reference of the DOM object and its ID)

Comment: I am using the same logic in the following file http://www.filedropper.com/filter_1 but it does not seem to be working. (I am C++ Programmer and new to JS/JQuery World so perhaps not Completely understood what do you want to explain.)

Comment: @user15662  the errors here were that instead of $(this) i wrote this, and instead of .parent().css(...) i wrote .parent().style(..). my mistake. i made a pen on my code pen ([link](http://codepen.io/CerrahogluAli/pen/PwKYwL))

Comment: @uer15662 i edited my answer , corrected the errors just mentioned in my previous comment and added a little explanation, with a bonus too :)

Comment: Thanks for kind help! Can i simply write count of ids in table as ids may be 100000 and hide them somewhere but on clicking the count (of ids) same logic will work?

Comment: @user15662 Of course. I will edit my codepen. Until then, i have some questions. Do you add ids or rows to the second table AFTER page load? Do you have that much ids?

Comment: Yes, when i reload default number of rows in second table will be displayed without filter. Yes i have that much ids.

Comment: I edited. what you said in the first sentence does not mean that you add more rows, just display them all. If you have that much rows than caching the rows from the first table is a must! Updated my codepen. Notify if you have problem with optimisation :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69665/discussion-between-cerrahoglu-ali-and-user15662).

Comment: Can i highlight the number/last column like hiperlink(like in href) so that it gives a feeling that number need to be pressed?