# HTML Div Equal Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made this javascript code, but i think i am repeating my self, so any suggestions to make this code more better and optimized.

```
var countHeight = [];
$('.box').each(function() {
    countHeight.push( $(this).outerHeight() );
});
var maxValueInArray = Math.max.apply(Math, countHeight);

$('.box').each(function() {

  $(this).css('height', maxValueInArray+'px');

});
```

Comment: What is your problem, be specific.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795318/map-get-confusion/4795529#4795529 this might help

Comment: There is no problem in code.. just need a little more optimize version of it

Comment: When looking for a code review, please use the http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is slightly shorter version. No need to use second loop to add the height to each .box element.

```
var countHeight = [];
$('.box').each(function() {
    countHeight.push( $(this).outerHeight() );
}).css('height', Math.max.apply(Math, countHeight)+'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one set of optimization i can think of

```
$(function(){

var maxHeight = 0;
$('.box').each(function() {
    var h = $(this).outerHeight();
    if(h>maxHeight) maxHeight=h;
});

$('.box').each(function() {
  $(this).css('height', maxHeight+'px');
});

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lubc858/3/)