# how to use map function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to `add` `10` number(digit) in each element using `map` function on button click.I tried like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>


    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <button class="add">ADD</button>
    <ul class="item">
      <li class="abc">123</li>
      <li class="pp">12</li>
      <li class="abc">78</li>
      <li class="ac">13</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
    $(function () {

        $('.add').click(function () {
            var $items = $('.item li');
            var $newItem =$items.map(function (i,item) {
                console.log($(item).text())
                return $(item).text() +10;
            });
            console.log($newItem)
        });

    });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Expected output**

```
133
22
88
23
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is actually to chain `.get()` after calling the `.map()` function, which will return you the array that you have constructed, e.g.:

```
var $newItem = $items.map(...).get();
```

The reason why `.get()` is needed is because `.map()` generates an **array-like object**. Since you have started off with a collection of jQuery objects (`$newItem`), it will return a DOM node list. In order to get the array you intended, you have to call `.get()` to return a true array (not a DOM node list). A better explanation of why this is needed is available here: [`map()` `get()` confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795318/map-get-confusion)

On a side note, `$(item).text()` will not be automatically casted into a `Number`. This means that if the value of the text if `123`, it is actually seen as a string. The `+` operator will concatenate but not perform addition, i.e. `$(item).text() + 10` will give you `12310` instead of `133`. In order to cast it to a number, simply [prepend a unary `+` operator in front of the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976627/how-to-add-two-strings-as-if-they-were-numbers): `+$(item).text() + 10`.

Here is a proof-of-concept example of your scenario, with the two modifications mentioned above applied:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.add').click(function() {
    var $items = $('.item li');
    var $newItem = $items.map(function(i, item) {
      console.log($(item).text())
      return +$(item).text() + 10;
    }).get();
    console.log($newItem)
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">ADD</button>
<ul class="item">
  <li class="abc">123</li>
  <li class="pp">12</li>
  <li class="abc">78</li>
  <li class="ac">13</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `$.each()` instead of `$.map()`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.add').click(function() {
    var $items = $('.item li');

    $items.each(function(i, item) {
      $(item).text(parseInt($(item).text()) + 10);
      
      console.log($(item).text())
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">ADD</button>
<ul class="item">
  <li class="abc">123</li>
  <li class="pp">12</li>
  <li class="abc">78</li>
  <li class="ac">13</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution using `map` method.

You have to use `Array.from()` method.

> The Array.from() method creates a new Array instance from an
>   array-like or iterable object.

Also, you should use `parseInt()` method in order to add two numbers.

```js
$(function () {
         $('.add').click(function () {
            var $items = $('.item li');
            var $newItem =$items.map(function (i,item) {
                $(item).text(parseInt($(item).text()) +10);
                return parseInt($(item).text()) +10;
            });
            console.log(Array.from($newItem));
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">ADD</button>
<ul class="item">
   <li class="abc">123</li>
   <li class="pp">12</li>
   <li class="abc">78</li>
   <li class="ac">13</li>
</ul>
```

I recommend you to use `each` method.`map` only create a new `array` by applying a provided `callback` function for every item.

```js
$('.add').click(function() {
  $('.item li').each(function() {
    $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text())+10);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add">ADD</button>
<ul class="item">
  <li class="abc">123</li>
  <li class="pp">12</li>
  <li class="abc">78</li>
  <li class="ac">13</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: please exchange the html with expected output

Comment: You can now remove the `Array.from` from answer. Clearly answers the question but don't you think this is doing more than just updating the numbers by adding 10 into it and will be slower.

Comment: @Tushar, maybe he want to view the array.

Comment: I think OP is confused with JS `map` and `$.map`.

Comment: @Tushar, yes, in this situation I recommend him to use `each` mehod, map only create a new array by applying a provided function for every item.

Comment: @user5711656, what about my answer ??

Comment: @user5711656 I thought you want to update the HTML by new value as said in question and also mentioned in comments here, but you accepted answer which does not do this. Maybe, you like the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding number into text. first you need to convert text to number using JavaScript parseInt(text) function.

```
parseInt(text here)
```

and using get() function on $.map function

```
$.map(function(){}).get();
```

it will return you an array

**Js**

```
 $('.add').click(function () {
     var $items = $('.item li');
     var $newItem =$items.map(function (i,item) {
         console.log($(item).text());
         return parseInt($(item).text()) +10;
     }).get();
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2krzf03/)